# Professor Knowfair's square dissection assignment

Tags: mathematics, geometry, dissection

While [at the public library with professor Knowfair](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/29397/professor-knowfairs-triangle-dissection-assignment), he also told me his plans for this week's assignment. He said:

> Dissecting a triangle is all fine and dandy, but squares are the real deal. For next week's assignment, I'm going to ask the $n$-th student to dissect a square into $n$ equal-area triangles.

You can't help but wonder: this time, is the professor fair? How many students will be able to complete their tasks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the answer is

> The professor is unfair - only students where n is even can complete their tasks.

because

> For all even n, divide the square on the diagonal, then use the solution to the previous triangle puzzle on each half symmetrically.  For odd n, 1 and 3 are clearly impossible. I suspect that pattern continues, although I did not verify it any further.
>
>  Edit: [Monsky's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monsky's_theorem) apparently states this.  How convenient!

Comment: Even if the pattern didn't hold for every odd, the Professor would still be unfair to at least 2 students, so he'd be unfair in general.

Comment: Well, I thought it'd take longer.